# Hierarchical Select in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I'd like to render hierarchical selects. Each option in a select may have its own unique child selects. Ultimately, I want something [image: like this].

I have a class called fieldSelect that represents a single select dropdown with an array of options:

```
export class fieldSelect {
    constructor(
        public options: Array<fieldOption>
    ){}
}
```

The fieldOption class represents a single option within a dropdown. It contains value, text, and children. The children portion is another select dropdown (making it hierarchical).

```
export class fieldOption {
    constructor(
        public text: string,
        public value: string,
        public children: Array<fieldOption>
    ) {}
}
```

[Here's the Angular mockup on git.](https://github.com/goodoldneon777/z-hierarchical-select)

Comment: I don't have a dropdown hierarchy sample, but I have a treeview that can show you how to create a recursive template: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/recursive-treeview-in-angular-2.0

Comment: so what you want to know actually ? you want dropdown that is dependent on its parent one ?

Comment: When a user selects an option from any dropdown, all of that option's descendants are rendered. So for example, when "Temperature" is selected its child is rendered. The first option on its child is "Single Test", which has its own child. The child for "Single Test" is then rendered. The first option on its child is "Degas Arrive", which has no children so no other dropdown are rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use your `select` component into itself recursively. The important parts are:

- Define an input parameter corresponding to the options (and children)
- Check if there is something to display
- Detect select box changes so you can initialize the default current element

Here is a possible implementation:

```
import {Component,Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {FieldSelect,FieldOption} from './data';

@Component({
  selector: 'sel',
  template: `
    <div class="root">
      <select *ngIf="options && options.length>0" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
        <option *ngFor="#option of options" [value]="option.value">{{option.text}}</option>
      </select>
      <sel *ngIf="currentOption" [options]="currentOption.children"></sel>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [ SelectComponent ]
})
export class SelectComponent {
  @Input()
  options:FieldOption[];

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.options && this.options.length > 0) {
      this.currentOption = this.options[0];
    } else {
      this.currentOption = null;
    }
  }

  onChange(opt) {
    let i = this.options.findIndex(elt => elt.value === opt);
    if (i >= 0) {
      this.currentOption = this.options[i];
    } else {
      this.currentOption = null;
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.options && this.options.length > 0) {
      this.currentOption = this.options[0];
    } else {
      this.currentOption = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can import this component and use it into another one, as described below:

```
import {Component,Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {FieldSelect,FieldOption} from './data';
import {SelectComponent} from './custom.select';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <sel [options]="select.options"></sel>
  `,
  directives: [ SelectComponent ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    var options = [
      (...)
    ];
    this.select = new FieldSelect(options);
  }
}
```

I used this data structure:

```
var options = [
  {
    text:'Temperature',
    value: 'temperature',
    children: [
      { 
        text: 'Single test',
        value: 'singlke-test',
        children: [
          { 
            text: 'Degas arrive',
            value: 'degas-arrive',
            children: [
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text:'Temperature1',
    value: 'temperature1',
    children: [
      { text: 'Single test1',
        value: 'singlke-test1',
        children: [
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

See this plunkr for more details: https://plnkr.co/edit/VutmZOpbNd15TxJnBqpE?p=preview

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Very close! The only issue is I need to be able to have multiple child selects in the same "tier".

Comment: Cool! What do you mean by "same tiers"?

Comment: In my mockup the selects are "Temperature"->"Single Test"->"Degas Arrive" which will give me the temperature when the steel arrived at our Degasser (I work in a steel mill and a Degasser removes carbon from the steel). But what if I want to know the temperature changed from "Degas Arrive" to "Degas Leave"? Then I would need "Temperature"->"Two Test Difference" and 2 selects in the 3rd generation (or tier) that let me select "Degas Arrive" and "Degas Depart". Like this: https://imgur.com/1PcgP2u